# Is there a better way to achieve this layout?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I've been scratching my head trying to achieve what seemed like a pretty simple layout at first but I'm still nowhere close. Basically a horizontally centered header and a form underneath. The part I'm having trouble with is vertically aligning the inputs with the header.

[image]

Below is an image of my solution and the code

[image: my solution]

```css
.main {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 1.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 9px solid #0993B8;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas:
        "title title title"
        "labelCid inputCid ."
        "labelPasswd inputPasswd ."
        ". inputSubmit ."
}

.main h3 {
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: title;
}

label[for="cid"] {
    justify-self: end;
    grid-area: labelCid;
}

label[for="password"] {
    justify-self: end;
    grid-area: labelPasswd;
}

input[id="cid"] {
    grid-area: inputCid;
}

input[id="password"] {
    grid-area: inputPasswd;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    justify-self: center;
    grid-area: inputSubmit;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <h3>Customer Portal Login</h3>
    <label for="cid">Customer ID</label>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <form id="loginForm"></form>
    <input form="loginForm" id="cid" name="cid" type="text" required>
    <input form="loginForm" id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="LOG IN">
</div>
```

The problem with this is that I included the header in the grid and I can't style the form separately to add padding and a background-color. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you thought about using bootstrap?

Comment: The form has no content because if I nest the inputs inside it I can no longer arrange them underneath the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put all of the required elements in the form and apply `display:grid` to *that* for layout?

```css
.main {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

form {
  display: grid;
  background: grey;
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 9px solid #0993B8;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "title title title" "labelCid inputCid ." "labelPasswd inputPasswd ." ". inputSubmit ."
}

.main h3 {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: title;
}

label[for="cid"] {
  justify-self: end;
  grid-area: labelCid;
}

label[for="password"] {
  justify-self: end;
  grid-area: labelPasswd;
}

input[id="cid"] {
  grid-area: inputCid;
}

input[id="password"] {
  grid-area: inputPasswd;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-area: inputSubmit;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h3>Customer Portal Login</h3>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <label for="cid">Customer ID</label>
    <label for="password">Password</label>

    <input form="loginForm" id="cid" name="cid" type="text" required>
    <input form="loginForm" id="password" name="password" type="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="LOG IN">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I was so close. Thanks for your answer